# Hosting the application in europe without a Premier account

Tags: google-app-engine

I've built a Google App Engine application mostly for European users. I recently learned about the possibility to host it in the EU, and I'd like to do that.

The documentation at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading states

> Note : If you have an App Engine Premier account, you can specify that your new application should reside in the European Union rather than the United States. For developers that do not have a Premier account, you will need to enable billing for applications that should reside in the European Union.

and

> You must specify this location by clicking the "Edit" link in the "Location Options" section when you register the application; you cannot change it later.

I'm a bit confused by this because you cannot enable billing on an application before creating it, and once created you cannot change its location.

My questions are

1. Am I missing something?
2. What would be the best way to move my application to Europe?

Comment: unfortunately, at least for now, app engine hosted in the eu is only available to premier partners. this is different to enabling billing. however, unless you have a specific requirement to host your data within the eu (ie legals), then i wouldn't worry about it - i've not noticed a difference in performance.

Comment: Perhaps the question's accepted answer should be updated to reflect [changes in GAE's offering](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28784262/152630).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**

App Engine [server location](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/location) is now open to all Developeres.

Bear in mind, this must be specified when the application is being register; you cannot change it later. Server Location options is available under `Show Advanced Options` on the Create Project. This will allow you to choose either `United States` or `European Union`.

Comment: Hi, do you know if the option to migrate the app from United States to Europe is now available? (even using paid services)

Answer (score 4):

It's now possible for any user to host an App Engine application in the European Union, and the docs have been updated to reflect that.